# Using variables in Transact-sql exists subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery

this seems like it should be extraordinarily simple, so I apologize in advance if this information is easily accessible on the transact-sql documentation pages. I searched myself, but couldn't seem to find anything.

I'm trying to modify a transact-sql statement that currently runs on our Windows server 2000 box. I want to check if a table in another database exists, and then do a bunch of stuff. The database name is given as a string argument, '@dbName'

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE CopyTables
@dbName char(4)
AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  @dbName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE 
           TABLE_NAME = N'MainTable')

BEGIN
     --Do Stuff
```

In it's current state, it doesn't like using the bare @dbName variable within the select statement. Is there special syntax for doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the following:

```
DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'master', @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'spt_monitor';
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM [' + @dbName + N'].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + REPLACE(@TableName,N'''',N'''''') + N'''';

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
EXEC(@sql);

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 BEGIN;
    -- DO STUFF
    SELECT NULL;
END;
```

There are a few shortcomings to this solution:

1) It requires that the user executing the statement has `SELECT` access to the other database's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

2) It has the side-effect of actually selecting the rows, so if you're using a reader to access the results, you'll have to call `reader.NextResult()` or `await reader.NextResultAsync()` because it actually outputs the results of the `SELECT` statement, rather than doing it in an `IF EXISTS` context.

Comment: Can't you just do `SELECT 1 FROM ...` instead of `SELECT * FROM ...`? This way `@@ROWCOUNT` is either 0 or 1.

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT would be either 0 or 1 anyways, since table names must be unique, but you're certainly correct. You could `SELECT 1` instead of `SELECT *`. The point of the statement is really just to see if the table exists, so either works.

Answer (score 2):

The below code should do what you want. As was mentioned previously, the account running the query would need the privilege to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMAs in the target database.

To future-proof your stored procedure, I'd also suggest increasing the length of the database name parameter and declaring it as an nchar or nvarchar in stead of char.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CopyTables
@dbName char(4)
AS
DECLARE
  @SQLStr nvarchar (max),
  @Params nvarchar (max),
  @Count tinyint;
SET
  @Count = 0;
SET @SQLStr = N'SELECT @qCount = 1 FROM [' + @dbName + N'].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N''MainTable''';
SET @Params = N'@qdbName char (4), @qCount tinyint OUTPUT';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLStr, @Params, @qdbName = @dbName, @qCount = @Count OUTPUT;
IF @Count = 1
BEGIN
     --Do Stuff
END; -- if
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

By merging the two solutions, we get this:

```
DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'master', @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'spt_monitor';
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM [' + @dbName + N'].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + REPLACE(@TableName,N'''',N'''''') + N'''';
DECLARE @Count INT;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@Count INT OUTPUT', @Count OUTPUT;

IF @Count > 0 BEGIN;
    -- Do stuff
    SELECT 'the table exists';
END ELSE BEGIN;
    -- Do stuff
    SELECT 'the table does not exist';
END;
```

This solution requires that the user executing the statement has `SELECT` access to the other database's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, but it does not have the side-effect of selecting rows, like my previous solution.